# How do you edit a text outcome in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im new to learning to code batch files.

Basically I have this script

```
@echo off
echo.
echo Current Serials-
echo.
wmic bios get serialnumber
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber
wmic baseboard get serialnumber
pause
```

Which has this output

```
Current Serials-

SerialNumber
Insert Serial Number Here

SerialNumber
Insert Serial Number Here
Insert Serial Number Here

SerialNumber
Insert Serial Number Here
```

But I want the output to look like this

```
Current Serials-

Bios SerialNumber- Insert Serial Number Here
Diskdrive SerialNumber- Insert Serial Number Here, Insert Serial Number Here
BaseBoard SerialNumber- Insert Serial Number Here
```

Comment: Try using powershell you can probably do something with -replace.

Comment: Or in batch, FOR /F, or in VBscript, some simple string manipulation.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67040415/how-do-you-edit-a-text-outcome-in-a-batch-file)